# Set environment variable in nested batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to factor out a piece of a batch file that sets an environment variable to another batch file. This piece is somewhat involved and I would rather not repeat it in multiple batch files. I won't over-complicate this post with the actual code I'm trying to run in the nested batch file, but will provide a simple example that shows what I'm trying to do and reproduces the problem.

Batch1.cmd

```
cmd.exe /c setvar.cmd abc def
set abc
```

setvar.cmd

```
set var=%1
set val=%2
set %var%=%val%
```

The error returned for "set abc" in Batch1.cmd is this:

> Environment variable abc not defined

I imagine cmd.exe starts up a new environment, because on return to Batch1.cmd, the variable does not exist.

Is there a way I can nest a batch file and keep the environment it creates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment block is not shared between processes. As you are starting a new `cmd` instance a separate environment block is created, changed and destroyed before returning the control to the current batch file, that will not see any change as it was done in a different process.

Use `call setvar.cmd abc def` to start the nested batch file in the current process.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setx <var> <val>` command to set an environment variable more persistently. For example:

```
setx WEBCAM_ADDR 192.168.0.101
```

(Note: There is NO equals sign (=) as with the regular set command)

I just went through this issue, trying to run batch files from windows.  This is better than having to write, say, a configuration file somewhere...